# What to call someone who doesn't like foreigners who lack manners and basic knowledge of the country and culture they are mixing themselves in?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, offensive-language, pejorative-language

For instance, a French person is coming from a different culture and hence may come across as being rude in a British person's eyes. Moreover, he is ignorant about the different culture in Britain and claims French superiority over Britain's present day culture based on events that took place in history.

I am not sure if, when I dislike this French person for these treats, it could be considered racism (because that's what I am being called all the time when I say what I don't like about that type of foreign people) or if there is a more accurate term for disliking these kinds of rude, ignorant and foreign people. They visit this country with a disrespectful attitude and indifference towards adapting or awknowledging Britain's own culture.

Comment: You are labelled racist because it appears you brand all foreigners as being rude, inconsiderate, ignorant, and arrogant. That's a pretty good description of someone who is prejudiced. Regardless of their origin, NOT all foreigners or visitors who come into the UK are like this.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I have been treated very very nice in every country in Europe.  I have a lot of love for foreigners.  Deep love.

Comment: I didn't mean I just dislike foreigners. I meant I dislike the ones who are unmannered etc.

Comment: @user76935 - there are different norms everywhere.  You might think someone is rude but they are trying to be polite.  Or maybe your hostility might make them rude.  If you feel off the bat that someone from another country will be unmannered, you are a bigot.  In my area we call that - hillbilly.  There are assholes in every country.  By just assuming that the foreigners don't know better you might have a better attitude.  A friend in Singapore asked me if I wanted slippers when I entered his house. I stayed in socks.  He says "Why do you not wear my slippers?"  I never thought about it.

Comment: @RyeBread - What would you call a person that entered your friend in Singapore's house, that would refuse and be offended if the Singaporean person asked him to wear slippers?

Comment: My friend was offended.  For two weeks.  He finally blurted out something about the damn slippers when he was drunk.  I told him it was no disrespect but I wasn't wearing damn slippers around his house no matter if they were made of bull feathers.  He laughed and made fun of me to the other Singaporeans... we continued to live.

Comment: Is there any word that would describe, regardless of whether you wore the slippers or not, a different person in the same situation as you, who would actually be offended if asked and refuse to wear the slippers?

Comment: A less charged term might to describe yourself as being "intolerant of rudeness" but this would include compatriots as well as foreigners. So are you against bad manners, discourtesy, rudeness and a refusal to respect other people's customs in general or only those from foreigners?

Comment: They are not rude, expecting them to "adapting or awknowledging Britain's own culture" is rude.

Comment: This question is not about the English language. Also, it's based on a misconception.

Comment: Yes, I would think I am slightly intolerant of rudeness. But some foreigners are indifferent, ignorant to the culture of Britain, so they lack an open-minded thinking and the knowledge about the culture here. I feel if you have the intention to mix with another culture, but refuse to gain any knowledge about that culture and basically act rude towards us British because all that person knows is bad, stereotypical knowledge, then I very much dislike that type of foreigner. Is there a word to describe this? I don't like the ....... foreigner or something like that.

Comment: @ Kris - So, would you call the Singaporean person, who expected RyeBread to wear slippers, rude? He expected RyeBread to wear the slippers and later, even after two weeks, blurted something out about them?

Comment: I feel like there are a lot of similar questions to this one these days and with the same answers. Is something going on?

Comment: @ermanen local British and european elections, and frayed tempers concerning immigration. http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-27497227 Brits always vote on Thursdays, Italy's election days are held at the weekend. (One of the few sensible things in Italy).

Comment: Hospitality and rudeness are cross-cultural. I would say certain foreigners *are* rude, and I would also say that you seem *inhospitable*. But if it's just foreigners that bring that out in you, you're prejudiced.

Comment: The British and Americans are the worst offenders in this anyway. Just go to the Costa del Sol in Spain or Acapulco in Mexico and you will see they make no attempt to blend into the national culture. So no, I don't know of a word that specifically refers to disliking foreigners who do not blend in to the local culture. But given our own behaviour, I think native speakers of English should be tolerant. At least most of the foreigners who visit us can speak some of the language.

Comment: I'm confused about if you're looking for a word to describe yourself or to describe the foreigner?  In the question, it appears you're looking for a word to describe yourself, but in your comments you appear to be asking for a word to describe the foreigner who 'refuses to blend in'.

Comment: I'll just throw this in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugly_American_%28pejorative%29

Comment: @steveverrill - I am confused by your point.  So a foreigner who has been enticed by the marketing and advertisement that leads them to Acapulco for 2 weeks is supposed to learn the local culture and blend in?  In general countries determine how much tourism they want.  Tourism brings in so much money for some countries it is their main product.  America has lots of tourism in places and I know the locals get upset sometimes.  But they should be upset with their country, that is facilitating foreign culture, not the foreigners who are spending money and doing their thing.

Comment: French is not a race.

Comment: [Definite duplicate](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4732/2085).

Answer (score 6):

[xenophobe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/xenophobe)

> one unduly fearful of what is foreign and especially of people of
>   foreign origin

Some would call that person a *bigot* because that person usually feels their way and norms are superior.

> having or revealing an obstinate belief in the superiority of one's
>   own opinions and a prejudiced intolerance of the opinions of others.

Comment: Agree that this is more common, and more specific.

Comment: If you don't like foreigners it doesn't mean you're a bigot. It means you don't like foreigners. Also such person is not a xenophobe, because he is not afraid of all foreigners, he has prejudice for foreigners who lack manners and ability to grasp basic cultural rules. Your characteristics are negative whilst such a person might only be described as conservative and respecting his own heritage. I would look for a neutral noun at least.

Comment: @AlaksiejN. - The OP himself states that he is called *racist* ***all the time***. If you think an answer is inadequate, then **submit one yourself**. Arguing in comments is rarely a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the person  you are describing can also be called a **chauvinist**

> - a person who believes  that his country, race, etc., **is better than any other**
>   pls. refer to Merrian-Webster for this definition.

[chauvinist](http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chauvinist)

> - Believing that the group one belongs to, be it of sex, creed, or color, is automatically superior to another's.

[Chauvinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvinism), in its original meaning, **is an exaggerated patriotism and a belligerent belief in national superiority and glory**. Its eponym is a seemingly apocryphal French soldier Nicolas Chauvin, who was badly wounded in the Napoleonic wars. He received a pension for his injuries but it was not enough to live on. After Napoleon abdicated, Chauvin was a fanatical Bonapartist despite the unpopularity of this view in Bourbon Restoration France. His single-minded blind devotion to his cause, despite neglect by his faction and harassment by its enemies, started the use of the term.
[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chauvinist,xenophobe,&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,chauvinist;,c0;.t1;,xenophobe;,c0)

> As China's economic and military might grow, the people's pride and nationalistic feelings rise. There's nothing wrong with promoting patriotism, experts say, but they warn against [chauvinism](http://www.cnn.com/2012/06/03/world/asia/china-foreigner-crackdown-florcruz/). "The Chinese have to be careful about underlying chauvinism which can lead them to behave inappropriately towards foreigners in the country, and in their foreign policy," said Zweig. - CNN
>
> Globalization, socio-economic status and welfare [chauvinism](http://cos.sagepub.com/content/54/3/228.abstract): European perspectives on attitudes toward the exclusion of immigrants - Oxford Journals
>
> Canadian unions’ [chauvinist](https://www.wsws.org/en/articles/2013/01/12/cana-j12.html) campaign against “temporary foreign worker” expansion

Comment: Is it still used like that?  If it is I will give you a vote.  Never really heard it used for anything other than gender in my life.

Comment: It appears it is, I added Ngran to compare it with xenophobe.

Comment: I am not contesting it isn't used but your ngram has nothing to do with it.  Chauvinist is used way more than xenophobe for sure but it almost always means a male that feels that females are inferior.  By just showing the word doesn't connect it to your meaning.

Comment: It appears it is, I added Ngran to compare it with xenophobe. Please look at the definition in Merriam-Webster dictionary, which can't be linked unfortunately. You are right, NGram can be misleading from a semantic perspective but to my knowledge the word is used in the sense I have shown.

Comment: Josh - if you think your ngram shows anything, than you aren't getting what I am saying.  You are graphing out basically a different meaning of chauvinist.  I would like to see some of the recent uses in a sentence.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - added links. Used not infrequently, to my surprise. Josh, sorry to add to your answer. Feel free to roll back. I was curious, and saw that your answer was good, so I added some examples.

Comment: While I think you're right, it doesn't really sound like this answers the question the OP is asking (what to call a person who dislikes such chauvinists when they establish themselves in another country).

Comment: @medica - Xenophobia was mentioned more in the article.  It seems chauvinism is used but maybe by non-native English writers.  I don't know.  I have never heard it outside of gender.  I think if you said that the OP was chauvinistic, almost everyone would think he puts down women.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I don't find the usage strange at all.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd - some of them do. But the point is, they're used fairly interchangably, and *Chauvanism* is used. It does seem extra-American, but hardly non-native.

Answer (score 0):

I would call the person **insensitive**.  And uncurious.  And it can go both ways. ;-)